# Need help creating a date/time function for an online store

Tags: php, datetime

I am writing a function that will output to the user if a store is open or not.

I wrote a fucntion named is_store_open() with a variable called $day which will have the current day of the week assigned to it.

Lets say it is  Saturday. it finds  the case for "Saturday" and checks the opening time and closing time for Saturday.

The problem that I am facing, is  when the store is open past midnight on Saturday. It then won't check the case for Saturday.

Instead will check the case for  Sunday. Which is not what I want, because it will show the store as closed when its open still open on "Saturday"

I wrote a function below that checks to see if the previous day closing hours are greater then the current time. If its true then return true and I guess that should fix the problem.

But when I wrote that it would give me an error saying that $saturday_close is undefined. I'm guessing its because its in a switch statement, and it does not equal to that day.

I'm a little bit confused on how to set this up. If anyone has a suggestion I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

```
 function is_store_open(){
    $set_time = strtotime("tomorrow"); // Lets just sat its Sunday for testing purposes

     $day =  date("l", $set_time); 

     $time_now =  mktime("00", "00", "00"); // Now lets say the time now is 12:00am

    switch ($day) {

     case "Saturday":
     $open = "11:00";
     $saturday_close = "1:00";
      break; 


     case "Sunday"; 
   if($saturday_close > $time_now ){//If the $monday_close hours are greater then the    current     time return false the store is still open
    return true;
      } else {
   $open = "2:00";
   $close = "22:00";
   }
   break;

     }
```

Comment: The store is not open at 1am on Saturday. Think of it like this- sat: 09:00-23:59:59. Sun: 00:00-01:00

Comment: I know that. This is for restaurants and that's how their stores are set up. They close 3:00am on Saturday and open Sunday 9:00am. If you google the restaurant hours it will say. Saturday 11:00am - 5:00am.

Comment: Never mind!. I figured something out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post your solution here for future readers. There's far too many "it's cool, I fixed it" questions on stack.

Comment: Awesome! Remember to mark your answer as correct too.

Comment: Maybe explain your reasoning why it works too (for future reference).

Answer (score 0):

```
class StoreOperationHours {


 public $time_now;  

 public function __construct() {
//$this->time_now =  mktime("2", "00", "00" ); // Now lets say the time now is 12:00am;
  $this->time_now = mktime(date('H'), date('i'), date('s'));
 }


 public $SaturdayOpenHours = "11:00";
 public $SaturdayClosingHours = "1:08:00";

 public $SundayOpenHours = "11:00";
 public $SundayCloseHours = "23:00";




 public function IsStoreOpen() {


    //$set_time = strtotime("tomorrow"); // Lets just sat its Sunday for testing purposes
    $day =  date("l", time()); 


    switch ($day) {


    case "Saturday":
    $this->SaturdayOpenHours;
    $this->SaturdayClosingHours;
     break; 


    case "Sunday"; 
    if(strtotime($this->SaturdayClosingHours) >= $this->time_now ){//If the $monday_close hours are greater   then the current time return false the store is still open

    return true;
    } elseif($e) {
     return false;
    }
    break;
```